# Run as administator only if one program is running

Tags: batch-file

i have 2 batch files. I want to do that the second one will open ONLY thru the first one bat file, and not by clicking on it.  And i also want it to start it as administator.
Is it possible ? Thank you so much for an answer.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but only if you accept that it can start by clicking, but only work if ran from the other. Your question however is too broad, and I'm therefore not answering it here.

Comment: In the second batch file you don't want to open by double clicking, you can use something like `if "%~1"=="" exit /b` and add a label with what you want the script to do after. In the other batch script, you can add the `call` command to the second batch and the label. [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas 'example.bat' am_admin & exit /b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , this one works. But if i doubleclick on the second batch file , it opens.  Please, what should i add in , that it will open ONLY with the command in the first batch you wrote ? and not by double clicking on it.